# Check if image exists in xslt

Tags: image, if-statement, xslt

My task is to check if image exist and display it. Upper node is Hotel.

Xml file:

```
    <PhotoList>
        <Photo>
            <Url>https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/hotel-word-golden-letters-
on-600w-378101848.jpg</Url>
        </Photo>
        <Photo>
            <Url>http://demotest.itravelsoftware.com/fotografije_itravel/7/715_636077306767263022.jpg</Url>
        </Photo>
        <Photo>
            <Url>http://demotest.itravelsoftware.com/fotografije_itravel/7/714_636077303419440444.jpg</Url>
        </Photo>
        <Photo>
            <Url>http://demotest.itravelsoftware.com/fotografije_itravel/7/539_636064349608545756.jpg</Url>
        </Photo>
    </PhotoList>
```

Xslt:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="PhotoList/Photo">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Photo != ''">
                    <td><img src="Photo" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
```

This doesn't display picture and i'm not sure if != '' could properly check if img does or doesn't exists.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "image exists". Your test only looks at the string-value of the `Photo` element - which is never empty in your example. If you want to test if there is an actual image file at the specified URL, that's a completely different question.

Comment: I want to check if image is in xml, not if image is dispayed on some web page.

Comment: Then post an example that also shows a case where the image is missing.

Comment: Be aware that by using, <xsl:for-each select="PhotoList/Photo"> you are inside the Photo element, and thus this: <xsl:when test="Photo will not find anything.  Use instead <xsl:when test="Url etc

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the code you are looking for is

```
<xsl:for-each select="PhotoList/Photo">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(Url) != ''">
            <td><img src="{Url}" height="100" width="100"/></td>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it's only useful if there exist `Photo` elements with an empty `Url` child. The function `normalize-space(Url)` assures that `Url` elements with only whitespace content are handled as empty.